# Not Able to upload file/attachment when recording script in badboy tool

Tags: jmeter, badboy

I tried recording a script via badboy tool. But, I am not able to record the upload file/attachment scenario as the file/attachment does not get uploaded when tried in badboy. This file upload takes place successfully when i try doing it on browsers like chrome, Internet explorer, Firefox etc. Can anyone suggest me on how to run the upload file scenario when using the badboy tool??

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `jmeter` tag - if you are recording file upload using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)  - you need to have that file under JMeter's "bin" folder, see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) guide for details.

My expectation is that Badboy acts in the similar manner.